# Adding a Python Entry Point without Running setuptools

Tags: python, celery, setuptools, django-celery

I am using a python library (`flower`) that installs an entry point into another library (`celery`) when you run `setuptools`. However, I want to keep both flower and celery within my application directory and not install it globally on the python system.  How do I install flower's entry point into celery programatically?

Note that the entry point is defined in `PKG-INFO` as follows:

```
[celery.commands]
flower = flower.command:FlowerCommand
```

There is a function `pkg_resources.load_entry_point` that seems to be what I want, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up using, which works fine but which is specific to celery and flower. I placed the following into my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'djcelery',
]
try:
    import flower.command
    import celery.bin.celery
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Flower will not be available: %s"%e)
else:
    celery.bin.celery.CeleryCommand.register_command(
          flower.command.FlowerCommand, name='flower')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)? It allows you to create local environments, so that you can install things for one application without the need for installing things globally. Here is a goof [tutorial about it](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/).

Comment: Many of the packages that I'm using are either not available on pypi, or I need really recent versions directly out of the git repositories. virtualenv is better suited for standard package installations, no? I don't think it will help all that much in my situation.